# How can I get Battlefield 3 to play nice as a Steam shortcut?

Tags: steam, battlefield-3

I put the shortcut to BF3 into Steam. I load it, and Steam immediately places me from 'In non-Steam game' to 'Online' as the battlelog page loads. I think it's to do with that weird online server browser.

I'm sure I've seen people on my friends list load it up and have it stay up. Is there some command line thing I need?

Summary: How can I make BF3 act like a normal non-Steam game in Steam?

Even better, is there a way to get rid of the stupid web page loading and have it in game or something?

Comment: IIRC there is a way to get steam to work with BF3, but you'll never have a way to bypass battlelog and work completely in game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can get the overlay to show up in any Origin game, but having the name be proper is another story...

Here's what you have to do, I can confirm that this works for me (the overlay showed up in-game):

[image]

If you change "Origin" to "Battlefield 3" in the Steam Shortcut, it'll show up as such in your friends list. However, this means every Origin game will show up as Battlefield 3.

Credit to [this reddit post.](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/kt9s3/how_to_use_the_steam_overlay_in_battlefield_3/)

Comment: I just managed to find this via trial and error. It works great for what I want. :D Shame BF3 is running so badly on my system.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible. When you start `bf3.exe`, it opens Battlelog and then exits.

> I'm sure I've seen people on my friends list load it up and have it stay up.

That's due to a quirk of how Steam handles non-Steam games that spawn more processes.

If you start `bf3.exe` while Origin is **not running**, it will start Origin and exit. Steam now assumes that the new Origin process must be the *actual* game, and monitors that instead.

So if you use the shortcut while Origin **is not** running, it will display you as "in non-Steam game" as long as Origin is still open. If you use it while Origin **is** running, it will exit immediately without spawning a new process for Steam to monitor.

Comment: I just shut down Origin and started bf3.exe, and it still exited.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck You mean it didn't show up in Steam, or the process exited? Because bf3.exe will exit no matter what, unless launched by Battlelog.

Comment: It did not continue to be in game in Steam; it didn't count Origin as the new process. I guess I could set the shortcut to load Origin, if there was a way to start BF3 immediately on load or something (but manually having to exit Origin after playing to stop Steam messing up is annoying)